# Why do I get an error when I run some examples from the online ggplot2 reference manual?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying the ggplot2 examples in the online reference manual, and particularly in [this page](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/stat_density2d.html), I fail to produce all but the first of the second example's plots.

```
> d + stat_density2d(geom="tile", aes(fill = ..density..), contour = FALSE) 
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, var, value = list(`NA` = NULL)) : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
In addition: Warning message:
Removed 34912 rows containing missing values (stat_density2d).
```

I have R ver. 2.10.1 and ggplot2 ver. 0.8.6

What is wrong?

Comment: What does `summary(d)` look like?  Are you sure that the data frame is okay, and that you are accessing the right columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be the bug reported here:
http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/6a7929d2b122efb2